# Black screen when trying to install ubuntu 13.10

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I am in need of some help. It has been 2 weeks since I bought my first ever windows laptop with the aim of replacing windows but I have been unsuccessful.

The hardware is as follows :
Asus 15' F550D with A8 AMD processor and Radeon HD 8670M graphics 
The laptops runs EFI "bios"

I managed to switch off Fastboot and Secure boot in EFI

so far I managed to to boot from USB which I mounted the Ubuntu 13.10 on but I can not get pass the GRUB menu as no matter when I chose I end up facing a black screen with back light on and I can not get anywhere beyond that.

I have tried the following with no success:

- alternative versions of ubuntu ( 13.04 , 12.10 and Kubuntu 13.10 {all 64 bit}) problem remains.
- editing the boot options in grub and using "nomodeset"

what can I try next ? any other suggestions ?

please help Windows 8 is sucking life out of me !!!

In a perfect world I would be aiming to have a dual boot system but if it's easier to lose the big virus living in my system , Windows 8, then i'm more than happy to go with that . ...

Comment: You could try installing via a command line [MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), but Ubuntu might not work after the install... I also believe that this can be done by another computer connected remotely :-s

Comment: I got around it by connecting to external monitor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: the potential issues are the partitioning sheme: you cannot boot"mbr" partitions on a "GPT" partitioned machine and vice versa. this partitioning can be set with multiarch installer usb but setting it is not the issue, rather matching it but let's set that asside a second it's possible the bootable usb you make are borked. try using (under windows) Rufus https://rufus.akeo.ie/ to make your ubuntu installer. it's the cleanest way I know of. also check your isos against checksums and consider newer (supported) versions of ubuntu. is there any reason why you're not getting the latest : AKA 17.04?

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid, but I think I may have (had) similar problem with my new Windows 8 preinstalled Lenovo G710 laptop. Here it is simply that after booting Ubuntu or - for example - GParted Live CD, the screen brightness is automatically set to zero. On this particular laptop I use I can control brightness by F11/F12 (or Fn+F11/Fn+F12 depending on BIOS setup's switch). I'm sorry if I misunderstood your problem.

Edit: not "set to zero brightness" but screen set off and therefore not F12 but F9 here ;).

Comment: zero backlight and black screen is not the same.

Comment: I wish it was as simple as that .. I have tied no to success ... thanks for your reply ...

Comment: has anyone got any other ideas ? solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I put in the CD, get the little install logo, then the screen goes black.

It has to do with the Radeon graphics card. When I install Puppy Slack, it works, but other distros just go to black screens. Can't even get to a point where I can uninstall NVIDIA.

I found a solution here:
http://turriebuntu.wordpress.com/general-ubuntu-pages/ubuntu-boot-freeze-lockup-it-stops-with-a-blank-purple-or-black-screen/

Copied and pasted just in case the link goes down:

Installed Ubuntu lockup
After you’ve installed Ubuntu the lockup is likely to return. The workaround is slightly different. Start your computer, and press the Shift when booting up, to get the Grub menu. Use the arrow keys to navigate/highlight the entry you want (it’s usually the first one).

Press “e” to get into edit mode. then look for the line containing “

.... quiet splash ....

using the arro keys move your cursor just past this point and enter the word nomodeset so that you now have:

.... quiet splash nomodeset ........

and press

Ctrl-x

to continue booting.

At that point you will need to make the change permanent. Open a terminal and:

gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub

Find this line:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”

and modify it to give:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash nomodeset″

Save your changes close gedit and run:

sudo update-grub

At that point and you should no longer freeze during bootup.

Comment: As this is not a constructive answer, please consider posting informations like these as a comment in the future.

Comment: Understood. My bad. I'm going to edit it to include new information that's actually helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out to be the built-in video drivers dropping the screen backlight brightness down to zero.

I had attempted to install Linux Mint 17.1 and Linux Mint 201403 on a Lenovo G710. Simply using the keyboard controls to adjust the screen brightness allowed me to continue with the install.

The answer from user227444 was helpful in this scenario.

If the issue is due to kernal mod incompatibility it may be wise to explicitly specify the mod to use in the grub startup script as defined here: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/842

Answer (score 0):

If You have BIOS with UEFI/EFI You should disable this option in it (BIOS menu -> boot options) - than You will be able to use Your external OS on USB to install it in on Your hard drive.